# Protractor - How to add if condition if element is visible so skip on this test case else do the actions below

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I've tried to add an "if" condition for test case with 2 alternative use cases,

The first one is **IF** it exists user so it should looking for the string of "idan+free@gmail.com" on the screen and skip on the test case to next,

**ELSE -** Perform the actions below.

**Test cases -**

```
describe ('Production - New Free Account Test Case', function() {

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var dashboardBtn = element(by.xpath('//div/md-sidenav/f-main-menu/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/button/div/div[1]/md-icon'));
    var noActivation = element(by.linkText("idan+free@gmail.com"));

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
    });

     it ('Production - Free Account - Activation', function() {
      browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(dashboardBtn), 30000);
      dashboardBtn.click();
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("div.task-header.font-smd.task-clickable.ng-binding.flex"))), 30000);
      noActivation.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
           browser.driver.sleep(1000);
           console.log("SKIPPED");
        } else {
          $$("div.task-header.font-smd.task-clickable.ng-binding.flex").get(1).click();
           var mainWindow;
              browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(
                function(handles) {
                   mainWindow = handles[0]; //at this point there should be only 1 window
                }
              );

            browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {    
               handles.forEach(function(handle) {
                 if (handle !== mainWindow) {
                    browser.driver.switchTo().window(handle)
                     //-=- switch to iFrame handler -=-
                    browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside both frames
                    browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("div.clean-white-box.short-registration"))), 30000);
                    browser.driver.sleep(2000); 
                  }
              });
           }); 
        }
      });
   });

   it ('Production - Free Account - From Activation to pricing table', function() {
      noActivation.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
           browser.driver.sleep(1000);
           console.log("SKIPPED");
        } else {
         element(by.id("pivot_user_attributes_password")).sendKeys("password");
         element(by.id("pivot_info_business_size")).click();
         browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('option[value="I do not have a business"]'))), 30000);
         element(by.css('option[value="I do not have a business"]')).click();
         browser.driver.sleep(1000);
         element(by.id("pivot_country_name")).click();
         browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css('option[value="United States"]'))), 30000);
         element(by.css('option[value="United States"]')).click();
         browser.driver.sleep(1000);
         element(by.id("pivot_phone_info")).sendKeys("1234567890");
         element(by.id("pivot_info_is_web_designer_false")).click();
         browser.driver.sleep(1000);
         element(by.css("input.green-button")).click();
         browser.driver.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("div.packages"))), 30000);
       }
     });
  });

    it ('Production - Free Account - Activation process has been completed', function() {
       noActivation.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
            browser.driver.sleep(1000);
            console.log("SKIPPED");
        } else {
          element(by.css("a.upgrade-button.signup-button.free-button")).click();
          browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css("div.tasks-container.layout-column"))), 30000);
          element(by.xpath("//div/div/div[2]/div/md-content/div[3]/f-tasks/div[2]/div[1]/f-task-block[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]")).click();
          expect(element(by.css("div.task-header.font-smd.task-clickable.ng-binding.flex")).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
        }
      });
    });

  it ('Production - Free Account - Empty pages - Calendar first launch', function() {
     noActivation.isDisplayed().then(function(isVisible) {
        if (isVisible) {
           browser.driver.sleep(1000);
           console.log("SKIPPED");
        } else {
          browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
          browser.driver.close();
          browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
         });
        }
     });
  });

});
```

**Error when running the test if the user is not exits -**

```
[31m Production - Free Account - Activation - fail[0m


  1) Test cases pul Frontage Sanity Test Production - New Free Account Test C Production - Free Account - Activation
   Message:
     [31mNoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkText("idan+free@gmail.com")[0m
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkText("idan+free@gmail.com")
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:209:20)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:205:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:1:63)[31m Production - Free Account - From Activation to pricing table - fail[0m


  2) Test cases pul Frontage Sanity Test Production - New Free Account Test C Production - Free Account - From Activation to pricing table
   Message:
     [31mNoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkText("idan+f.com")[0m
   Stacktrace:
     NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkText("idan+f.com")
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:238:20)
From: Task: Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:237:4)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Sanity_Testing_node_12_2/testCases/newApp/freeUserTC.js:1:63)[31m Production - Free Account - Activation process has been completed - fail[0m
```

**The element:** -

```
<div class="email font-xs ng-binding">idan+free@gmail.com</div>
```

Comment: @alecxe - http://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe 
Please your help!

Comment: Quick question: does the `by.partialLinkText()` instead of `by.linkText()` make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: No, It receives the same error @alecxe - NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.partialLinkText("idan+free@gmail.com")

Comment: Okay, what if you add a wait there as well: `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(noActivation), 30000);`?

Comment: Now the error is related to this wait command @alecxe - "Error: Wait timed out after 30020ms"

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `ignoreSynchronization`? If your page is angular, you might not have to use so many browser.waits if you just let protractor do its job. Since you didn't post your page's html source, keep in mind that `linkText` only works for `<a>` elements. Another thought occurred that you might have to escape the + or @ symbols with a backslash.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML source of the page containing the email link? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, actually not all the pages are Angular and in some test cases it should open non-angular popups. I've add the HTML element as part of the main post, please check this out. - @alecxe  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `by.linkText`, as well as `by.partialLinkText` would work for *`a` elements only*.

In your case, you have a `div` element which you need to filter *by text*. You can either go with:

```
element(by.xpath("//div[. = 'idan+free@gmail.com' and contains(@class, 'email')]"))
```

Or with [`by.cssContainingText`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText):

```
element(by.cssContainingText(".email", "idan+free@gmail.com"));
```